# scanf taking multiple char inputs

Tags: c, char, scanf

```
int main() {
 char a1, a2;
 printf("input values here: ");
 scanf(" %c%c ", &a1, &a2);
 printf("%c%c",a1,a2);
}
```

I am trying to understand how scanf works when it is given two character inputs at once. After running this in terminal with 14, for example, I had expected to assign 1 to a1 and 4 to a2 but it did not work. Given that I must separate a terminal input of "a4" for example, into two seperate chars, how would I go about doing so? Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

```
./main
input values here: 14
```

Comment: `" %c%c "` ==> `" %c%c"` no space at end

Comment: yea that worked well thanks a lot.

Comment: Checking the **return** eliminates all mystery and will tell you exactly what conversions took place and what didn't. [man 3 scanf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) explains the rest.

Answer (score 4):

With [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) when it sees a space in the format string, it will read (and discard/ignore) any number of white-space characters. And for that to work, the `scanf` function needs to find the end of the non white-space characters.

The problem with a trailing space, like you have in your `scanf` format string, is that to find the end of the trailing white-space sequence you must enter at least one extra non white-space character.

The simple solution to your problem (as I guess it is) is to drop the trailing space in the `scanf` format string.